# Do Adapters limit the Middleware pipeline count to only allow 2 IMiddleware to be used with Use()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, middleware

From testing the [BotBuilder Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/901bc140f5aa300fbfa852e64afd7c65fceebff9), I am trying to extend one of the examples to use multiple [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.imiddleware?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) classes in the pipeline. I have found that the BotAdapter only uses the first 2 IMiddleware classes added. Even if I try the BotAdapter's [MiddlewareSet.Use()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.middlewareset.use?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_MiddlewareSet_Use_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_IMiddleware_) method, it still limits to only the fist 2 added. The documentation for IMiddleware does not state anything about the pipeline being limited to the first 2 added. Does anyone know anything about this and how to get past this 2 limit?

We cannot use Skills as we want to avoid having dozens to hundreds of app registrations in our organization. Any help is appreciated.

Pseudo code sample to show where calling multiple Use() methods will limit to 2:

```
        public AdapterWithErrorHandler(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger, ConversationState conversationState, SkillHttpClient skillClient = null, SkillsConfiguration skillsConfig = null)
        : base(configuration, logger)
    {
        ...
        Use(new LoggerMiddleware1(logger));
        Use(new LoggerMiddleware2(logger));
        Use(new LoggerMiddleware3(logger)); // <--- Never gets invoked!!!
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you post the the LoggerMiddleware(1-3) source? There's no limit to the number of middlewares. BTW what are you using for logging?

Comment: If middleware 3 doesn’t get called, that would mean middleware 2 didn’t call its `next` delegate.

Comment: That could be one option, the other I can think of now is with logging itself, the log trace could get lost in the logger cache, specially if you're running this in automated testing, and the logger isn't flushed properly.

Comment: if a middleware is not invoked, that means it's short-circuited somehow. You need to examine the before middlewares to find out the possibilities for that kind of short-circuiting.

Comment: @MiguelVeloso Thanks!!! I went back to the code just now and you are right, I was not calling next() in one of the middleware and it stopped the flow. My fault :(

Comment: @KingKing yes you are right. I ended up finding the bug a little while ago, I was not calling next() in one of the middleware causing it to short-circuit as you stated. Thanks for the help 

Comment: @ckuri yes, you nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that one of the Middleware's was not calling `next` causing the next middleware in the pipeline to not get called. Thanks to the commenters for helping.

```
await next(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This line needed to be called in the `OnTurnAsync` handler to trigger the next middleware in the chain.